# Adding a New Row to a Dynamically Created HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I found a great little widget that creates an HTML table with an input text field that allows a user to insert text in the fields and add a new row at the bottom with a button click.  After the data is added, it has a button to allow the user to download the table as a CSV file.  It works great but I’m trying to update it with a new feature.

Currently, the table is hand-written in the HTML.  This is great when I want the user to input in new data in a clean input text field or add/update data that is already in place.  I still have a use for this option.

The new option I like to offer, the user can update existing CSV data in the table.  I manage to replace the hand-written HTML with a dynamically created table from an existing CSV file.  Everything works except for adding the new row.  The new row shows but it’s not formatted correctly (just slightly off) and instead of adding one new row at the bottom like the original concept it adds several new rows sometimes (random number of rows).  Other then that everything works as expected.

I have gone over the script, but I can’t manage to fix’s this problem.  The dynamic table is created with D3.js and a CSV file; everything else is JavaScript/jQuery/, HTML and CSS.    Any help to see what I’m missing would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Update Table and CSV</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3Tip.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>-->


<style>
body {
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container{
width:95%;
height:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid rgba(153,153,153,1);
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
overflow:hidden;
}
.header {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color: grey;
}
.btn{
width: 6.5em;
height: auto;
margin-right: .5em;
padding: .2em;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1em;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: relative;
float: right;
top: 1.2em;
cursor: pointer;
}


.content {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
.footer{
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color: grey;
}
#clear{
clear: both;    
}



/*Table Style*/

.btn {
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-blue {
 background: #3498db;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
 }

 .btn-blue:hover {
 background: #3cb0fd;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
 }

 .btn-green {
 background: #75c987;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #468054);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #468054);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #468054);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #468054);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #75c987, #468054);
 }

 .btn-green:hover {
 background: #75c987;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #75c987);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #75c987);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #75c987);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #75c987, #75c987);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #75c987, #75c987);
 }

 #inputsTable{
 margin:20px 0;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 50;
 }
 input{
 width:150px;
 }
 .input-id{
 width:20px;
 }
 .input-graphic{
 width:100px;
 }
 .input-date{
 width:100px;
}
.input-marker{
 width:200px;
}
.input-imageCount{
width:200px;
}
.input-speed{
width:200px;
}

table { 
width: 100%; 
border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
background: #eee; 
}
th { 
background: #333; 
color: white; 
font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
 padding: 6px; 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
text-align: left; 
}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

        <div class="header" ></div>

        <div class="content">

                        <h1>Update</h1>

                        <table id="inputsTable"></table>



  <a href="#" class="btn btn-green" id="addRowBtn">Add new table row</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue" id="lnkFile"  download="productData.csv">Download CSV file</a><div id="clear"></div><br><br>

        </div><!--Close content-->


        <div class="footer"></div><!--Close footer--> 

</div><!--Close container-->


<script>

 d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("#inputsTable")
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")
                    .attr('class',function(d) { return  'csv-row'})

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter().append("td")
                    .append('input')
                    .attr('type','text')
                    .attr('name','textInput')
                    .attr('value', function(d){ return d;});
 });



$(document).ready(function(){
(function($) {
var ieOldFn = null;
var getRandomNumber = function() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
};
var addRowClick = function() {
$("table").find("tr:last").clone().appendTo($("table"));
$("table").find("tr:last").find("input").each(function(ind, el) {
  if (ind === 0) {
    var id = parseInt($(el).val());
    $(el).val(id + 1);
  } else {
    $(el).val('');
  }
  });
  updateCsvLink();
  };

  var updateCsvLink = function() {
   var csvString = "id,graphic,date,marker,imageCount,speed";///CSV file  header
  $(".csv-row").each(function() {
   csvString += "\n";
   var separator = "";
  $(this).find("input").each(function() {
    csvString += separator + $(this).val();
    separator = ",";
  });

  });

  var fileName = 'productData.csv';
  console.log(csvString);
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkiURL;
  var blobObj = new Blob([csvString]);
  var lnkElement = document.getElementById('lnkFile');

  if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob != "undefined") {
  var clickFn = function() {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObj, fileName);
  };
  if(ieOldFn !== null){
    lnkElement.removeEventListener('click', ieOldFn, true);
  }
  lnkElement.addEventListener('click', clickFn, true);
  ieOldFn = clickFn;
  } else {
  var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobObj);
  lnkElement.setAttribute('href', fileUrl);
  lnkElement.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  }
 };


 $('#inputsTable').on('change', 'input', updateCsvLink);
 $('#addRowBtn').on('click', addRowClick);


  updateCsvLink();
 })(jQuery);


 });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is the hand-written HTML table being replaced with the dynamic table.

```
  <table id="inputsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>graphic</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>marker</th>
      <th>imageCount</th>
      <th>speed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="0" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide1.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="510" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="3" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="5000" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="1" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide2.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="520" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="2" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide3.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="530" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="3" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide4.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="540" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="4" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide5.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="550" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="5" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide6.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="560" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="6" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide7.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="570" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="7" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide8.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="580" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="8" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide9.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="590" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="9" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide10.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="600" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="10" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide11.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="610" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="11" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide12.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="620" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="12" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide13.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="630" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="13" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide14.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="640" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="14" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide15.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="650" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="15" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide16.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="660" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="16" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide17.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="670" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="17" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide18.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="680" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="18" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide19.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="690" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="19" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide20.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="700" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="20" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide21.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="710" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="csv-row">
      <td><input class="input-id" readonly value="21" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-graphic" value="Slide22.JPG" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-date" value="08/01/2016" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-marker" value="720" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-imageCount" value="" ></td>
      <td><input class="input-speed" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>-->
```